# An open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $n > 2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm taking an introduction to algebraic topology course and this is one of the assigned problems. We have computed the fundamental group of the circle and we have proved that $S^{n}$ is simply connected for $n \geq 2$. This way we can prove the result if we replaced "set" with "ball". Indeed, an open ball in $R^{n}$ is homeomorphic to $R^{n}$, and $R^{2}$ can't be homeomorphic to $R^{n}$ for $n > 2$ because $R^{2} - \{x\}$ has non-trivial fundamental group while $R^{n} - \{y\}$ is simply connected.

So I have been trying to prove that a given homeomorphism $f : U \rightarrow V$, $U \subset R^{2}, V \subset R^{n}$ open sets, can be restricted to give a homeomorphism between balls. We start by taking a point $u \in U$. Take a ball $B_{1}$ around $u$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a ball $A_{1}$ around $v = f^{-1}(u)$ such that $f(A_{1}) \subset B_{1}$. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, there exists an open ball $B_{2}$ around $u$ such that $f^{-1}(B_{2}) \subset A_{1}$. Thus clearly $B_{2} \subset f(A_{1})$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed here. It just seems like I'll keep going forever, getting smaller and smaller balls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a ball in $V$.
 Then $A$ and $f^{-1}(A)$ will be homeomorphic and for $a\in A, \ A-\{a\}$ is simply connected while the fundamental group of $f^{-1}(A)-\{f^{-1}(a)\}$ is non-trivial (is $\pi_1\left(f^{-1}\left(A\right)\right)* \mathbb Z$).

To see this, suppose $\pi_1\left(f^{-1}(A)-\{f^{-1}(a)\}\right)=0$ to conclude that $\pi_1\left(\mathbb R^2-\{f^{-1}(a)\}\right)=0$ ↯.

Comment: But why is the fundamental group of $f^{-1}(A) - \{f^{-1}(a)\}$ non-trivial?

Comment: @Pedro Look at a small neighborhood of $f^{-1}(a)$: it is a disk minus its center. The fundamental group is the same as for the circle, that is, $\mathbb Z$. (Punctured disk can be retracted to a circle).

Comment: The fundamental group will be $\pi_1(f^{-1}(A)) \ast \mathbb Z$, not $\pi_1(f^{-1}(A)) \times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AlexanderThumm: Thanks.